# Linus(centos) + nginx "Warning: socket_bind() [function.socket-bind]: unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in /home/chat/ws-api.php"

Tags: php, linux, sockets, centos6.5

I created a php socket server for group chat and I am trying to run it on Linus(centos) + nginx, and I have been trying for about 3 days without success. It keeps giving me this error

> Warning: socket_bind() [function.socket-bind]: unable to bind address
>   [98]: Address already in use in /home/wwwroot/chat/ws-api.php on line
>   96

I searched on line and, I tried to **change port number** many times with many different port numbers, no success.
I tried to **run it through command line (CLI)**, no success.
I tried to **run it directly through the browser**, no success.
Please tell me how am supposed to solve this problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check current used ports using

netstat -tlnap

and check if other services are using the same port. If yes stop that service and start nginx